# Call to a member function getMonthDays() on null

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a strange issue that I cannot figure out, I want to pass the month from the post into the function but it returns the error stated in the title?

The `$_POST["month"]` does have a value which is a string of the month (e.g. April). The strange part is the function does work when I use `date('F')` to get the text version of the current month.

PHP on the view :

```
if(isset($_POST['month'])){
    $monthDays = $race_calendar->getMonthDays($_POST['month']);
}else{
    $monthDays = $race_calendar->getMonthDays(date('F'));
}
```

The PHP function :

```
public function getMonthDays($month){
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare('call getMonthDays(?)');
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $month);

    if($stmt->execute()){ // Executes MYSQL procedure and checks if it was successful or not.
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

My config.php file (included at start of index):

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/classes/race_calendar.php");

// Details to connect to the database
$servername = '****';
$username = '****';
$password = '****';
$dbname = 'racing_calendar';

// Connect to the database
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check to see if the connection failed
if($connection === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$race_calendar = new race_calendar();
$race_calendar->connection = $connection;
```

Comment: try: if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['month']))

Comment: @KlevinDelimeta I know that the post is not empty, if i put an echo within the if statement it outputs the value as expected.

Comment: Your issue is not that `$_POST['month']` is null. Your error message is telling you that `$race_calendar` is null, and not a valid class instance. Need to debug why.

Comment: @Sean how would the same call below it work if there was an issue with that?

Comment: If it works when the `else` is being called, it means `$_POST['month']` is not set. So that would lead me to believe you are not setting `$race_calendar` on a `$_POST`.  Need to look at where you call `$race_calendar = New {yourClass}`, and make sure it is not in an `else` block.

Comment: My class is set in my config file which is then included via the index which makes it accessible to all my other files. The if stated above is the only difference as to which version is called.

Comment: Then somewhere in your code you are overwriting `$race_calendar` and making the class instance null.

Comment: @Sean Could it be the fact that i include the file originally and then replace it with an ajax version when the user selects the month? would that replicate?

Comment: @LewisBlundell Every time the script runs it starts fresh, no variables persist except for `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @Barmar but i am posting it from an ajax request so wouldnt $_POST still work for that request?

Comment: The problem is with `$race_calendar`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: @Barmar is there an other information i can add to the question which could help solve this issue? its completely stumped me

Comment: Post the part of the script that sets `$race_calendar`.

Comment: @Barmar hope the additional code will help?

Comment: As someone else said, you must be overwriting the variable somewhere. Put `var_dump($race_calendar);` at various places in the script, and see when it prints `NULL`.

Comment: @Barmar i am unable to find the cause by using 'var_dump' by the time it calls the ajax file it is null

Comment: Problem was solved. Missed put the include for the config file at the top of my ajax file